# How do I convert InMemoryUserDetailsManager to use a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have found many answers to this question using an embedded database, but I cannot find a solution to converting InMemoryUserDetailsManager to specifically a MySQL database. Does anyone know how to do this?

I've attached the classes I think are specifically related to this issue, and I only have the backend code here.

SecurityConviguration.java:

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.access.BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public SecurityConfiguration(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    //This is an in memory database, which adds users below.
    //TODO: Connect to MySQL in order to add an Add User page.
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService user(){
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                User.withUsername("user")
                        .password("{noop}password")
                        .authorities("read")
                        .build()
        );
    }

    //Configures server to authenticate user
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())//Configure cors security
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) //disable cross-site request forgery
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                        .mvcMatchers("/token").permitAll()//Authenticate using "controller/AuthController"
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() //authorize all requests from spring
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))//disable session
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt) //Configure with token from front end to backend.
                .exceptionHandling((ex) -> ex
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler())

                )
                .build();
    }

    //Decodes Encrypted Token to access user profile
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    //Encodes profile information into token
    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    //Connects to Front End
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(){
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:5173"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


}
```

RSAKeyProperties.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa")

public record RsaKeyProperties(RSAPublicKey publicKey, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {


}
```

AuthController.java:

```
import com.example.Commerce_Bank_Back_End.model.LoginRequest;
import com.example.Commerce_Bank_Back_End.service.TokenService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController 
public class AuthController {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);
    private final TokenService tokenService;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthController(TokenService tokenService, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    //Authenticate using Postman, then generate token to be stored to the header.
    //************************************************************************

    @PostMapping("/token")
    public String token(@RequestBody LoginRequest userLogin){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLogin.username(), userLogin.password()));
        return tokenService.generateToken(authentication);
    }
}
```

TokenService.java:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtClaimsSet;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoderParameters;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder encoder;

    public TokenService(JwtEncoder encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }


    //Generate Token for Logged in Session
    //************************************************************************

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `JdbcUserDetailsManager`. Add the mysql connector dependency to pom, configure the `DataSource` manually and `return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(ConfiguredDataSource);`. Or just add the specific properties to application.properties (the dependency is still a must) ([spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/), but there are many more, just google it) and spring will take care of everything, no need to declare the bean manually.

Comment: @Chaosfire, do you mean like this? ```@Bean
    public UserDetailsService user(){
        return new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    }```

Comment: @Chaosfire, I now receive this error in the console: "auth.ts:17          POST http://localhost:8080/token 401
login @ auth.ts:17
(anonymous) @ pinia.mjs:1362
store.<computed> @ pinia.mjs:915
onSubmit @ LoginForm.vue:15
(anonymous) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1483
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345
auth.ts:34 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid Credentials!
    at Proxy.login (auth.ts:34:23)"

Comment: You should edit question to add what you tried and the error, if there is error on the backend side, add it as well. This error is from the frontend, i see js and ts, i can't say how it is related to your change. The only random guess i can make is, did you add the user in the database?